# React, how do I persist the state of side drawer selected list item with router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router and material UI. I integrated the routes with my material UI persist drawer list items with some custom styling like when I click on a list item it highlights it. But I'm facing an issue when I refresh the page my selected list item gets reset, even though I'm still on the same page. Can anyone tell me how do I persist the selected list item even if a page gets refreshed?

**Inshort**: *Issue*- when I refresh the page my drawer list item selected color get reset to top item even though I'm on the same page.

Here is the gif to demonstrate my issue[image]

Here is my sandbox code [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-the-routes-in-react-router-dom-forked-whr5o?file=/src/App.js)

Below is the code for the same

**Note:** I would suggest you go through my code sandbox it'll be better for you to lookup in code. Thank you

**App.js**

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import "./styles.css";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Dashboard.jxs for nested routes in dashboard**

```
import { Switch, Redirect, Route, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${path}/about`} component={About} />
          <Route path={`${path}/home`} component={Home} />
          <Redirect to={`${path}/home`} />
        </Switch>
      </NavBar>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

**NavBar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import SideDrawer from "./SideDrawer";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  hide: {
    display: "none"
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: 0
  }
}));

export default function NavBar({ children }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    if (!open) {
      setOpen(true);
    } else {
      setOpen(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Persistent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {/* child compoent to render side drawer and state is passing to open & close */}
      <SideDrawer open={open} />
      <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
        {children}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**SideDrawer.js its a child component inside NavBar.js**

```
import {
  useTheme,
  Divider,
  Drawer,
  IconButton,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemIcon,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import DrawerList from "./DrawerList";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  }
}));

const SideDrawer = (props) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { open } = props;
  return (
    <Drawer
      className={classes.drawer}
      variant="persistent"
      anchor="left"
      open={open}
      classes={{
        paper: classes.drawerPaper
      }}
    >
      <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {/* my component to render list of icons in side drawer */}
        <DrawerList />
      </List>
    </Drawer>
  );
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

**DrawerList.js child component of SideDrawer.js** ***Issue is arising here***

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import { DashboardOutlined, AddCircleOutline } from "@material-ui/icons";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import { makeStyles, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { Link, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  iconStyle: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0, 0),
    color: "#676767"
  },
  iconTitle: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0, 0, 0, 1),
    color: "#676767"
  },
  listItem: {
    "&.Mui-selected": {
      // it is used to change external svg color during click
      "& path": {
        fill: "#fff"
      },
      margin: theme.spacing(1.5, 1)
    }
  }
}));

const DrawerList = ({ children }) => {
  console.log(children);
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  const itemList = [
    {
      text: "Home",
      icon: <DashboardOutlined />,
      keys: "home",
      to: `${url}/home`
    },
    {
      text: "Appointment",
      icon: <AddCircleOutline />,
      keys: "about",
      to: `${url}/about`
    }
  ];

  const ListData = () =>
    itemList.map((item, index) => {
      const { text, icon, to, keys } = item;

      return (
        <ListItem
          className={classes.listItem}
          button
          key={keys}
          to={to}
          component={Link}
          selected={index === selectedIndex}
          onClick={(e) => handleListItemClick(e, index)}
          style={
            selectedIndex === index
              ? {
                  background: "#3f51b5",
                  width: 200,
                  marginLeft: 8,
                  paddingLeft: 10,
                  borderRadius: 4,
                  boxShadow: "2px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
                }
              : {}
          }
        >
          <ListItemIcon
            className={classes.iconStyle}
            style={selectedIndex === index ? { color: "#fff" } : {}}
          >
            {icon}
            <ListItemText>
              <Typography
                component="div"
                className={classes.iconTitle}
                style={selectedIndex === index ? { color: "#fff" } : {}}
              >
                <Box fontWeight={700} fontSize={13.8}>
                  {text}
                </Box>
              </Typography>
            </ListItemText>
          </ListItemIcon>
        </ListItem>
      );
    });

  const handleListItemClick = (e, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ListData />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DrawerList;
```

Comment: Redux might help you in achieving your requirement.

Comment: @NirajPatel but that's a small project I don't want to use any state management library. Can't you suggest any easier method?

Comment: Then as suggested by TJ, you can use localstorage.

Comment: @NearHuscarl yes that's the answer to my question however Domino987 has already answered with the same solution. But I appreciate your efforts. Thank You :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to track the url to show the selected items instead of a useState that gets reseted:

```
  
  const { url } = useRouteMatch()
  const {pathname} = useLocation();


  const itemList = [
    {
      text: "Home",
      icon: <DashboardOutlined />,
      keys: "home",
      to: `${url}/home`
    },
    {
      text: "About",
      icon: <AddCircleOutline />,
      keys: "about",
      to: `${url}/about`
    }
  ];
... 
selected={pathname === to}
```

Comment: OMG, This is what I was looking for.. I was thinking there might be a way to do this without local storage or state management and bingo you came here to help me the way I wanted. Thank you soo much. I really appreciate it :-D

Answer (score 1):

To persist data between page refresh, you can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API.

You need to initialize your state with the value from `localStorage`. And whenever you update your react state, you also need to update the value in `localStorage`, so that after page is refreshed, your component state gets initialized with this stored value.

For eg:

```
const storedOpen = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('drawerOpen'));
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(storedOpen);

const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
   if (!open) {
     setOpen(true);
     localStorage.setItem('drawerOpen', true);
   } else {
     setOpen(false);
     localStorage.setItem('drawerOpen', false);
   }
};
```

[image: Edit whats-the-best-way-to-separate-the-routes-in-react-router-dom (forked)]

Comment: But I think it can be done without local storage too...this example has done it but I'm unable to understand it... https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mig8cf-xeyvep?file=app/DrawerContainer.jsx

Comment: @user9824674 in your codesandbox I can only see "Login" how do I trigger other routes? Can you make one with only the component you have trouble with?

Comment: please see there are three routes /  ,    /dashboard     ,         /dashboard/home      ,      /dashboard/about. I have trouble with /dashboard route

Comment: @user9824674 see the sandbox in answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I appreciate it but as you can see Domino987 answers we can do it with pathname too without using local storage which seems better I presume :-) But I really wanna say thanks to you :-)

Comment: Is state of side drawer something that you would like to display in URL? That sounds like internal application state to me. That practice is going to give you really long unreadable URLs in the long run when there is enough nested components

Comment: Oh, you're totally right. Can you please suggest some best practice for that?.

Comment: I found this http://www.smallbusinesssem.com/7-rules-for-writing-urls/2043/, application state in URL goes against 1 and 3

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a really so informational article that will definitely be needed when my project grows more. I appreciate it :-)